# Removing Xamarin Profiler from Visual Studio 2019 for Mac

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2019 installed on macOS 11.2 Big Sur. For the last month or so, it has been prompting me every day to install an update for Xamarin Profiler. When I click to proceed, it starts to install and then fails without any sort of message (it just exits the update).

I don't use Xamarin and am tired of it prompting me every day for this same update. Is there a relatively painless way to uninstall Xamarin Profiler from Visual Studio 2019 for Mac that *won't break everything else*?

I tried looking for how to uninstall components, but the Microsoft docs looks like you have to run weird scripts, and I am afraid of breaking anything .NET-related in my development environment and not being able to fix it.

I just want the update nag to go away.

EDIT: IIRC, other updates have been installing. It just seems to be stuck on this one.

[image: Visual Studio 2019 for Max Updates are Ready]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I want the update, because I use Xamarin. It seems to be a side effect of installing the Visual Studio 2022 preview side-by-side with 2019.

[This problem has been reported on the Developer Community and is under investigation.](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Xamarin-Profiler-161568-not-installin/1630658?space=41&entry=problem)

I did manage to solve the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling VS2019, however.